# Unhandled exception at C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, pointers, string-literals

I receive this error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00091e11 in JobTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0009573c.
```

on first line of this function

```
void myFunction(char str[]) {

    str[0] = 'C';// here is a problem
    printf(str);
}

myFunction("Hello World");
```

in visual studio 2010. Is it compiler specific or i am doing really bad job.
i also tried by changing function signature char *str.

Comment: String literals hold constant data. This shouldn't even compile as of C++11.

Comment: You tried to write to a read-only string constant.  That's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are non-modifiable. You are trying to modify a string literal in function `myFunction`.
String literals might be shared and could be stored in read-only memory (as @Duplicator said in his comment). Any attempt to modify a string literal invokes **undefined behavior**.

As @MooseBoys suggested, You can fix it by changing it to:

```
char msg[] = "Hello World"; 
myFunction(msg);
```

Comment: You can fix it by changing it to: `char msg[] = "Hello World"; myFunction(msg);`

Comment: "String literals are stored in read only section of memory.": Better: String literals might be shared and could be stored in read-only memory.

Comment: @Deduplicator; Not bad. Adding that too :P